# Transform QuerySet or Json into Recordset

Tags: django, aspose

All

I am working on Django and Python. I wanna call aspose dll library with pywin32. The Aspose dll for merge mail (dynamic load data and render it into template) need RecordSet data type. So, is it any way to transform queryset into recordset? Thanks :)

Here a example for python to call aspose.
http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Python+and+Aspose.Words+for+.NET

Answer (score 1):

RecordSet type is not necessary, if you have name/value pair, you can call doc.MailMerge.Execute() method with other data source type arguments, example shown [here](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/How+to++Execute+Simple+Mail+Merge).

PS. I am a Developer Evangelist at Aspose.